# How to get specific values from dataframe using attributes in the columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

My dataFrame looks like this.

[image]

i only want the values for ford and honda and amc. Is there any way i can get these values.

I tried this but its not working.
    x= grouped["ford", "buick" , "honda"].agg([np.min, np.max, np.mean])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

```
brand=["ford", "buick" , "honda"]

df_new=df[df['brands'].isin(brand)]
```